# Updating System Admin profile creates new System Admin profile?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, jsforce

I am using JSforce to update the System Admin profile to view a field that I am creating right beforehand.

After creating the field I am using JSforce's update metadata method to update a custom profile and the System Admin profile. For whatever reason the custom profile works fine but there seems to be a new System Administrator profile that gets the correct permission while the other System Administrator profile isn't updated at all.

This is what I'm seeing in the field permissions:[image]

This is my JSforce wrapping code:

```
app.service('metadataService', function() {
    var connection;

    this.connectToSalesforce = function(salesforceSessionId){
        connection = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: salesforceSessionId});
    }

    this.createMetadata = function(metadataType, metadata, callback){
        connection.metadata.create(metadataType, metadata, callback);
    }

    this.updateMetadata = function(metadataType, metadata, callback){
        connection.metadata.update(metadataType, metadata, callback);
    }
});
```

calling code:

```
metadataService.updateMetadata('Profile', profileMetadata, function(error, profilePermissionsResults){
    //blah blah blah
});
```

Comment: Odds are, you simply did something wrong. Maybe you created a new profile by accident? Using any metadata tool to update field security would not create a new profile.

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you sure you are using `updateMetadata` instead of `createMetadata`

Comment: @Eric I added wrapping and calling code